# I cannot ping my guest operating systems via Bridged Network Connection

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, ping

Here are the details:

I am using VMWare Workstation 9.0.1 build-894247.

- Host - Windows 7 - Firewall is turned on - has static IP
- Guest OS 1 - Windows Server 2008 R2 - Firewall is turned off - has static IP
- Guest OS 2 - Windows Server 2008 R2 - Firewall is turned off - has static IP

#### additional info

- I cannot ping my guest operating systems even though I used Bridged network connection.
- I assumed that the IP addresses of the guest operating systems are already visible in the network, but they are not.
- The guest operating systems CAN ping the host.
- The guest operating systems are ABLE to ping each other.

Here is the sample result:

```
C:\Users\asus>ping 192.168.0.117
Pinging 192.168.0.117 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.166: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.167: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.254: Destination host unreachable.
General failure.
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What have you used to Virtualize? VirtualPC, VMware or something else?

Comment: Hi. Sorry about that. I have just edited my post. I am using VMWare Workstation 9.0.1 build-894247.

Comment: Have you tried changing the settings for the NIC for the guest machine? I believe there is an option there to change it to Bridge/NAT/custom network.

Comment: Well, yes, there are options there. I can only use the bridged network connection because I want my virtual machines to be accessed in the entire network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the OS of the virtual machines have their network discovery turned on. Also, make sure that the default gateway and the DNS server IP addresses are correct.

Regards,

Lester